# Is it possible to write a URL-string that updates/refreshes a given webpage with a certain interval?

Tags: javascript, url

I have encountered scripts that are:

1. an inline java-script code
2. appended to the url

These scripts manipulate the web-page and the one I have encountered save the whole twitter archive as a .csv-file.

What is the name of this type of scripts?

Is it possible to write such script to refresh a web-page constrantly by an interval of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but Scripts in a URL is most likely [Cross-Site-Scripting](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Scripting) (XXS)

Reloading a page can be done with window.[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)("window.location.reload();", 1000) or window.setInterval("window.location.reload();", 1000)

Answer (score 0):

This script should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function refresh() {
    location.reload(true)
  }

  window.setInterval("refresh()",300000); // every 5 minutes

</script>
```

Comment: this a script, I need an inline script which I can paste into the address bar of my browser